# Convert int to date format dd / MM / yyyy in Android

Tags: android, date

I am developing an application in which I need to get the last sent SMS. All good so I'll know the date of shipment. With the expression int cursor.getColumnIndex indexDate = (DATE) I get an integer but I need to convert a date eses integer format dd / MM / yyyy and then convert that date to String. How I would do?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "dd / MM / yyyy" *is* a String/text value representing a date. Anyway, the first step is to *identify* what the integer value represents. Is it encoded like 20130403? Or is it Unix epoch time? Other? Or is this question simply about *reading* a Date from the database (the posted code is incomplete and unclear)?

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
int dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("date"); //integer represent date you get from db
Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(dateColumn)));  
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd " + "\n" + "hh:mm:ss");  
String date = dateFormat.format(d);  // formatted date in string
```